# Are $a/3, b/3$ equivalent to $1/3(a), 1/3(b)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following expression with two answers, I'm not sure if they're correct:

$1/3(a+b) = 1/3 (a) + 1/3 (b)$ can the answer be:  $a/3+ b/3$ too?

Comment: Tey are the same if you menas $1/3 \times (a+b)$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{3}(a)=\frac{a}{3}$, so yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at it this way:
$$1/3(a+b)=\frac{1\cdot(a+b)}{3}.$$
We know that when we multiply anything by the number 1, nothing changes, and therefore
$$1/3(a+b)=\frac{a+b}{3}=\frac{a}{3}+\frac{b}{3},$$
so you are correct.

Also, you wrote
$$\frac{1}{3}(a)+\frac{1}{3}(b),$$
which can be rewritten as
$$\frac{1\cdot a}{3}+\frac{1\cdot b}{3}=\frac{a}{3}+\frac{b}{3}.$$